# Defining the lines in a vertical histogram

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that returns a vertical histogram where the height of each column corresponds to an integer from a list. I have written some code that I think would work if I could find a way to define each line.

If the goal is not clear I'm trying to write a program with a function that takes a list
(ex. [1, 5, 2, 4])
and returns a vertical histogram consisting of asterisks like this:

```
 *  
 * *
 * *
 ***
****
```

Below is the code that I think could work if I manage to define row in a nice way.

```
def render_histogram(values):
    histogram = []
    for y in range(max(values), 0, -1):
        row = ()
        histogram.append(row)
    return '\n'.join(histogram)
```

My first idea would be to check for every column if the number in question is equal or greater than y, but I don't know how I would write this as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My first idea would be to check for every column if the number in question is equal or greater than y, but I don't know how I would write this as code.

Yes, that is the right approach. You can do that as follows:

```
    row = ''.join(' ' if x < y else '*' for x in values)
```

The rest of your code is fine, but you could also turn that `for` loop into list comprehension, so that you get this function:

```
def render_histogram(values):
    return '\n'.join(
        ''.join(' ' if x < y else '*' for x in values)
        for y in range(max(values), 0, -1)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This code calculates maximum value of the list, and fill the difference of each item with blank spaces:

```
def render_histogram(values):
    max_val = max(values)   # Max value in list
    result = []
    for item_val in values:
        bar = " " * (max_val-item_val)     # Fill with spaces
        bar += "*" * item_val              # Fill with "*"
        result.append(bar)
    return result


data = [1, 5, 2, 4]
hist =  render_histogram(data)
for line in hist:
    print(line)

# Prints: 
#     *
# *****
#    **
#  ****
```

If you need to print in vertical mode, just iterate the `hist` array properly:

```
x = len(hist[0])
y = len(hist)

for i in range(x-1, -1, -1):
    for j in range(0, y):
        char = hist[j][i]
        print(char, end="")
    print("")

# Prints:
# ****
#  ***
#  * *
#  * *
#  *
```